# php extract a sub-string before and after a character from a string

Tags: php, regex

need to extract an info from a string which strats at 'type-' and ends at '-id'

```
IDlocationTagID-type-area-id-492
```

here is the string, so I need to extract values : area and 492 from the string :

After 'type-' and before '-id' and after 'id-'

Comment: What you have tried so far? Post your attempts too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want using two explode.

```
$str = 'IDlocationTagID-type-area-id-492';
echo explode("-id", explode("type-", $str)[1])[0]; //area    
echo trim(explode("-id", explode("type-", $str)[1])[1], '-'); //492
```

Little Simple ways.

```
echo explode("type-", explode("-id-", $str)[0])[1]; // area
echo explode("-id-", $str)[1]; // 492
```

Using Regular Expression:

```
preg_match("/type-(.*)-id-(.*)/", $str, $output_array);
print_r($output_array);

echo $area = $output_array[1]; // area
echo $fnt = $output_array[2]; // 492
```

Comment: too many explode, but it pushed me to the idea of using ArrayIterator (+1)

Comment: This question must be tagged as regular expression.

Comment: You have mistake in preg_match. You code in string "$str = 'IDlocationTagID-type-area-id-492fdfgdgdg" return:
array(
0 => type-area-id-492fdfgdgdg
1 => area
2 => 492fdfgdgdg
)
but id must be int

Comment: What is demand of OP?? **After 'type-' and before '-id' and after 'id-'**??? `after 'id-'`....

Answer (score 2):

You can use the preg_match:
For example:

```
preg_match("/type-(.\w+)-id-(.\d+)/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

To check, you may need the service:

> http://www.phpliveregex.com/

**P.S.** If the function preg_match will be too heavy, there is an alternative solution:

```
$str = 'IDlocationTagID-type-area-id-492';
$itr = new ArrayIterator(explode('-', $str));
foreach($itr as $key => $value) {
    if($value === 'type') {
        $itr->next();
        var_dump($itr->current());
    }
    if($value === 'id') {
        $itr->next();
        var_dump($itr->current());
    }
}
```

Comment: Regular expression is not tagged, so i make it using only PHP.

Comment: May be you can more optimize this expression.

Answer (score 1):

You can use explode to get the values:

```
$a = "IDlocationTagID-type-area-id-492";
$data = explode("-",$a);
echo "Area ".$data[2]." Id ".$data[4];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match('/type-(.*?)-id/', $yourString, $matches);
echo($matches[1]);
```